# C opendir always NULL

Tags: c, null, opendir

So I am working on a directory traversal, and I am unable to get opendir to work the way I want it to. It always fails to open the directory I send it, it gives some unknown error. I usually pass in argv[1], but I gave up and just started hard coding paths.

```
char *dest = NULL;
char *filePath = ".";
char *newPath = NULL;


DIR *dirp;
struct dirent *dp;
int errno;
dirp = opendir("/home/cs429/Desktop/test");

struct stat path_stat;



if(dirp == NULL);
{
    // Error Handling
    fprintf(stderr, "Error failed to open input directory -%s\n",strerror(errno) );
    return 1;
}
```

Does anyone see what I could be doing to get NULL? I also get this in gdb:
../sysdeps/posix/opendir.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: Does the folder exist? what happens when you type `cd /home/cs429/Desktop/test` in the terminal. Check the case of the path.

Comment: please enable all warnings. This is something that is detected by gcc or clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
if(dirp == NULL);
```

does nothing, and the next code block is always executed, regardless of the value of `dirp`.

Please remove the `;` so the code is

```
if(dirp == NULL)
{
    // Error Handling
    fprintf(stderr, "Error failed to open input directory -%s\n",strerror(errno) );
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: note that `gcc -Wall` (or clang) warn about this: `foo.c:4:1: warning: this 'if' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
 if(dirp == NULL);
 ^~`

Answer (score 0):

first check given path really exist or not.

```
dirp = opendir("/home/cs429/Desktop/test");
```

man pages says "The **opendir()** functions return a pointer to the  direc‐tory  stream.   On  error, **NULL** is returned"

here you compared `dirp` with `NULL` thats correct but you putted semi-colon after `if` statement, thats called `dummy if` i.e whether condition is true or not, immediate statements will executes always. So remove the `;` after `if`

```
if(dirp == NULL)
{
  //some code
}
```